# ThreeJs: Check if Object is in center of Camera

Tags: 3d, three.js, frustum

I'd like to check if a cylinder is more or less in the middle of the camera to perform an interaction then. The cylinder operates like a button.
My idea was to check with the frustum, but I have no idea, how to adjust the z-axis.
Or may they be a better option?

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
frustum.setFromMatrix( matrix );
if(frustum.containsPoint( cylinder.position ))
  cylinder.material.color.setHex( '0xbada55' );
else      
  cylinder.material.color.setHex( '0xffcc00' );
```

This checks if the cylinder is in view and not, if in the middle range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raycasting is expensive.

The simplest way is to project the cylinder position into screen space and check if it is close to the center of the screen. This way, you can also define a threshold for how close to center it needs to be:

```js
var threshold = 0.2;

var positionScreenSpace = cylinder.position.clone().project(camera);
positionScreenSpace.setZ(0);

var isCloseToCenter = positionScreenSpace.length() < threshold;
```

I have made a demonstration of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/holgerl/z199hzgd/

Comment: Thanks! 

One advantage with raycasting is that you can tell if something else is in front of the object. In that case, it might be that the button should not be clickable. Like if it is around the corner of a wall. But it depends on the use case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`raycast`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster), using [`camera.getWorldDirection()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/Camera.getWorldDirection) as the target.

Something like this:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, camera.getWorldDirection());
```

And then check if your desired object was hit.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

if (intersects && intersects[0].object.id == myObjectId) {
    // Object is in the center of the camera
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ne7gjdnq/103/)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using raycasting: You cast a ray from the center of the viewport into the scene and check if that ray intersects any of the objects. In principle, this is the code you need:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var center = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
var raycastTargets = [
  // add objects (meshes) that should be subject to raycasting
];

function render() {
  // ...

  camera.updateMatrixWorld();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(center, camera);

  var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(raycastTargets);
  var intersection = (intersections.length) > 0 ? intersections[0] : null;

  // ...
}
```

After that code in the render-function, you will see in `intersection` if the object in question is in the center of the view.